# Wordpress - Document Viewer from user's files

Tags: wordpress

So I have a wordpress site where users login to a page that has a text editor (tinymce) that saves their content to a database.

I want to create another page where users can view their content. But I always want to allow them to upload pdfs, docx, and other formats to the database and view it in this viewer as well.

Not sure if there's a plugin that can help but any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a link to find the answer of this question. kindly visit it 
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is important to put essential parts, cotext, details in this post. Link only answers are discouraged in stack overflow.

Comment: I guess that's good for copy & paste for content in a word doc but I am looking for a solution that can load other formats into a viewer rather than just copy and paste, extending to pdfs and other types.